# Is there an "undecided" assertion of which a proof that it's not undecidable is known?

Tags: lo.logic, independence-results

Just a curiosity:

> Is there an assertion of which a proof (formalizable, say, in ZFC) is not known but a proof that it's *not* undecidable (in ZFC) *is* known?

Edit: after the comments, I think the actual question was

> Is there an ("interesting") assertion of which neither a proof (formalizable, say, in ZFC) of it or its negation is known but a proof that it's *not* undecidable (in ZFC) *is* known?

Comment: Well, $0 = 1$ will do... There is no known proof that is formalizable in ZFC, but it is known that $ZFC \vdash \lnot(0 = 1)$, regardless of whether ZFC is consistent or not. (Since quid might scold me again for being unclear: I'm writing this because what you wrote is probably not what you meant...)

Comment: See David Speyer's answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62144/are-the-millennium-prize-problems-all-decidable

Comment: @GZaimi: thank you for the link, it's exactly in the spirit of what I (think I) was asking. The example given by D.Spyer clearly answers my question. If anybody knows other examples, answers are welcome.

Comment: Any decidable but (so far) infeasible open problem. Such as: what is the 5th Ramsey number? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_number)

Comment: A simple way to put your question: "Is there an assertion in ZFC which is known to be decidable but has not been decided yet." The answer is YES, see the link in Gjergji Zaimi's comment.

Comment: Since it is established that any computationally infeasible problem will do, how about tweaking the question to ask about problems that are decidable, yet not obviously so?

Comment: I see. Thanks to the various comments I notice that an answer to my question doesn't involve anything particularly "deep", but it's just a matter of cooking up a computationally challenging "problem".

Comment: In fact deciding any decidable assertion is nothing more than a computationally challenging problem: one simply needs to generate all possible proofs in ZFC and find the one which decides the assertion.

Comment: Reposting a link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/190855) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [Are the Millennium Prize Problems all decidable? \[closed\]](https://mathoverflow.net/q/62144)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's known that some statement $S$ is decidable in ZFC, then you can just run a computer program that enumerates all ZFC-proofs and stops when it finds a proof of $S$ or a proof of $\neg S$.  By hypothesis, this algorithm is guaranteed to terminate.  Therefore, the only possible obstacle separating decidable statements from decided ones is computational complexity.

In other words, the only possible instances of what you're looking for are statements that have already been proved *up to a finite computation*.  Until they were actually proved, the Kepler Conjecture and Catalan's Conjecture were perhaps the most interesting examples of this type.  I can't think of other examples of comparable interest offhand, but maybe others can.

Comment: The odd Goldbach problem is only known for $n<10^{18}$ or $n>e^{3100}$, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture.

Comment: Another one which was of comparable interest until it was settled: Is there a simple group of order 808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000 ? Clearly checkable by finite computation!

Comment: @Timothy: Your response elaborates on my earlier comment above.

Comment: @GH: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until after I posted.  (By the way, I had already made essentially the same comment in response to David Speyer's answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62144/are-the-millennium-prize-problems-all-decidable )

Comment: @Timothy: That's all right, in fact it is always good to give more detail!

Comment: @KevinVentullo : A couple of years after you originally posted your comment, Helfgott announced a proof of Goldbach's weak conjecture. The proof seems to have been generally accepted, so that's another potential example that has "bitten the dust."

Answer (score 11):

It shouldn't be hard to find a large number $N$ such that no one knows a proof that $N$ is prime and no one knows a proof that $N$ is not prime. Yet the question of the primality of $N$ can't be undecidable - there is a simple (if impractical) algorithm for deciding it.

Comment: How about a handsome tower of 2's plus 1?

Comment: Is $2^{43112621}-1$ prime?

Comment: @Gerald: Hmm. I may be misinterpreting it, but my reading of http://www.mersenne.org/report_exponent/?exp_lo=43112600&exp_hi=43112699&B1=Get+status is that its Lucas–Lehmer residue, independently confirmed by two people (with another failed attempt), is nonzero, therefore the number is composite, even though no explicit factor is known.

Comment: @GHfromMO For that sort, we can make it even worse if instead of primality we ask whether the number has an even or odd number of distinct prime factors, and if we add a small amount to it to make sure that there isn't any hidden pattern involving numbers very close to powers of 2, then we could ask if 2^2^2^2^2^2^2 +35 has an even or odd number of distinct prime factors. This is decidable. But there also is likely not enough computational power in the observable universe to answer this essentially simple arithmetic question.

Answer (score 7):

There's tons of assertions like that in finite combinatorics.  For example the Ramsey numbers R(5,5) and R(6,6) can be "straightforwardly" (i.e. given impractically large computing resources) found by direct enumeration.  It's known that $43\le R(5,5) \le 49$ and $102\le R(6,6)\le 165$.  But Wikipedia's article on Ramsey theory quotes Joel Spencer:

> Erdős asks us to imagine an alien force, vastly more powerful than us, landing on Earth and demanding the value of R(5, 5) or they will destroy our planet. In that case, he claims, we should marshal all our computers and all our mathematicians and attempt to find the value. But suppose, instead, that they ask for R(6, 6). In that case, he believes, we should attempt to destroy the aliens.

The article [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) has another interesting example.